# Error in Intercom.bundle when trying to install 'Intercom' pod via Cocoapods

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoapods, intercom

When attempting to install the Intercom pod in my Xcode Project, I get an error in the console:

```
[Intercom] ERROR -  The Intercom.bundle hasn't been added to your app correctly. This will result in images not appearing in the SDK's messaging UI. More information on how to correctly integrate Intercom is available here: https://developers.intercom.com/docs/ios-installation.
```

Comment: The error message seems to be incomplete. And please format it as a quote.

Comment: Would you please give us the complete error message or a screenshot and tell us what's your cocoapods version

Comment: cocoapods version 0.39.0

Answer (score 1):

Seems something is not right with the way cocoapods installed Intercom. Maybe corrupt, by doing these step it will clear all the cocoapods and start fresh. Which might solve your problem.

Open your Podfile and copy the existing pods you have listed there (The Podfile is in your project directory).

Close your Xcode workspace.

1. Open Terminal
2. `cd` to the directory of your project.
3. run `pod deintegrate` from Terminal
4. delete all files and folders related to cocoapods (Podfile, Podfile.lock, Pods folder and the xcworkspace file) if there are any left.
5. run `pod init` from Terminal
6. add the list of pods to the Podfile in the directory save it.
7. run `pod install` from Terminal

Open xcworkspace file in your project folder.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on files marked red in xcode -> delete, then it should be solved :)